# Formatting result of multiply operation that getting from two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

1. Problem 1

   ```
   SELECT 
   f.MANHOUR_TOTAL,
   f.MATERIAL_TOTAL,
   e.NILAI_RATE * f.MANHOUR_TOTAL AS LABOUR_TOTAL
   ```

   Which is the existing data is e.NILAI_RATE = `4.00` and MANHOUR_TOTAL = `11.00`. The result is 44.0000.
   How to keep two digits behind comma on LABOUR_TOTAL as 44.00
2. Problem 2, I want to use those LABOUR_TOTAL to next operation like this :

   ```
   SELECT 
   f.MANHOUR_TOTAL,
   f.MATERIAL_TOTAL,
   e.NILAI_RATE * f.MANHOUR_TOTAL AS LABOUR_TOTAL
   LABOUR_TOTAL + f.MATERIAL_TOTAL AS FINISHING_TOTAL
   ```

   But it gives me null value on FINISHING_TOTAL. Is it possible to do like this ? Any help and suggestions is so appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For Problem 1 you want ROUND:

```
SELECT ROUND(e.NILAI_RATE * f.MANHOUR_TOTAL, 2) AS LABOUR_TOTAL
```

should do it!

For Problem 2, consider this:

```
SELECT 
f.MANHOUR_TOTAL,
f.MATERIAL_TOTAL,
ROUND(e.NILAI_RATE * f.MANHOUR_TOTAL, 2) AS LABOUR_TOTAL,
ROUND((e.NILAI_RATE * f.MANHOUR_TOTAL) + f.MATERIAL_TOTAL, 2) AS FINISHING_TOTAL
```

Comment: Good to hear!  Thanks for upvoting the answer, Don't forget to also accept the answer :)